# spring integration http outbound gateway timeout handling

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have http outbound gateway that post json message to rest service, now the rest will response with http error status with json message type in case if there is any error which should captured by our application. in happy scenario which post json message to that rest service and got http success status and json message also should captured with our application.

Now what I achieved through spring integration I was able to send message and got success response and capture it but in error status the spring behavior it throw an exception how can I change the behavior?

also how can make retry if there is any timeout ?

below the http outbound gateway configuration

```
    <int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="aggregatorChannel" reply-channel="responseChannel" charset="UTF-8"
    url="http://localhost:8090/receiveGateway" http-method="POST" reply-timeout="180000">               
    <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain >
        <int:retry-advice max-attempts="5" recovery-channel="aggregatorChannel" >
            <int:exponential-back-off initial="1000" multiplier="5.0" maximum="600000" />
        </int:retry-advice>
    </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

the above configuration will retry on the error message which I don't want retry on that, I want to retry if there is only timeout.

Answer (score 3):

What do you want to change the behavior to (when there's an error)?

If you wire up the `RetryTemplate` for the retry interceptor manually, as a `<bean/>`, you can specify in the `RetryPolicy` which exceptions are retryable.

**EDIT:**

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but maybe this will point you in the right direction...

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel" 
                           url="http://localhost:8080/http/receiveGateway"
                           http-method="POST"
                           request-factory="requestFactory"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
    <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain >
        <int:retry-advice max-attempts="5" recovery-channel="foo">
            <int:exponential-back-off initial="1000" multiplier="1.1" maximum="600000" />
        </int:retry-advice>
        <bean class="foo.MyExceptionAdvice" />
    </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<bean id="requestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <property name="connectTimeout" value="5000"/>
    <property name="readTimeout"    value="5000"/>
</bean>
```

If the custom exception advice throws an exception, the message will be retried and eventually sent to he recovery channel. If the custom advice consumes the error, it can send a return value. I have put a simple on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/a9706f464032fc48b71d).

Comment: good! but how also can make the retry on timeout connection?

things for the first glance its easy but how to tailor them kind of mystery, can you please mention how to that in the above configuration ?

Comment: it seems we can't implement that on timeout?

Comment: See the [javadocs for the `SimpleRetryPolicy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/retry/policy/SimpleRetryPolicy.html) for how to configure exceptions for which you want retries to be applied.

Comment: I tried `CompositeRetryPolicy` and pass these polices `TimeoutRetryPolicy` and `TimeoutRetryPolicy` but I got http connection timed out and doesn't retried

Comment: Did you read the [section about handling timeouts](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http-timeout) in the reference manual? You should only need a `SimpleRetryPolicy` once you have the timeouts configured properly.

Comment: I read it and did the `HttpFactory`! but still not retry on the timeout!! and I used `SimpleRetryPolicy` and no retry!!

BTW also the section mention that if you didn't specify that spring will use `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` which also they said not recommend to use it. I used instead of that Apache HttpComponents HttpClient and still the same issue!

Comment: should I remove `<int-http:request-handler-advice-chain >` ?
BTW regarding to the any http status I want it to make it success message

Comment: No, you need to advice to retry. If you still can't figure it out, post a DEBUG log somewhere (e.g. gist.github.com). You'll need to use an expression evaluating advice (with `trapException`) to convert an exception to a good result.

Comment: can you give me hints how to translate the exception through SpEL?
if you want I can update the question and put the full stack and full updated configuration

Comment: I added some suggestions to my answer.

Comment: sorry for being late, first the timeout is not working with the above configuration! 
second is the advice exception will override the default one ?